# html elements alignment

Tags: css, select, html, input, label

I have the following html elements:

```
<fieldset style="margin:20px;border:5px solid red;padding:0;">

        <label class="offset widget" >Title goes here</label>   
        <input class="offset widget" style="padding:0" type="text" name="fname">
        <div class="offset" style="position:relative;width:120px;display:inline-block;">
            <select class="widget" style="position: absolute; left:0;top:0;">
               <option value="en_KW">English</option>
               <option value="ar_KW">Arabic</option>            
             </select>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

and the css style:

```
            .offset{
            margin-left:40px;
            margin-right:0;
        }
        .widget{
            width:120px;
            height:16px;
            text-align:right;
            text-height:16px;
            font-size:11px;
            font-family:arial;
            border:2px solid black;
            float:left;
            padding:0;
        }
```

Also on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tPzqG/5/

1) why if I set the div display to inline the margin is not taken into account? Label and text input elements are also inline elements and the margin is considered.(in chrome, not in firefox)

2)why the select height is smaller than the height of the label and text input, although the height is specified for the three of them and it is the same?

3)text align does work for label but not for select (only in chrome). is it possible to fix this without direction:rtl?

4)why if div height is not specified while the div display is inline-block then the div moves below the fieldset?(only in jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As you can see in developer tools on Chrome the div element has 0x0 dimension. It's becouse  you put block element to inline element. And it is not correct. Remember when you set float, or position absolute to element it becomes block element automaticly.

2) One again I link to Chrome developer tools. In developer tool you can see that browser engine little bit diffrent computes height of select element. It takes borders heights included.

in normal situation:
real height =  height + borders top, bottom heights + paddings top, bottom heights

in this case:
real height = height - borders top, bottom heights + borders top, bottom height

3) Styling select doesn't work - it's normal situation. Redering select element it's complitated to browser and browser doesn't allow that. Of course there is a exceptions, but in each browser it is diffrent

4) I think it's becouse the same thing like in first point. Browser layouting process goes wild and computes offset of element wrong.

I recommend you to read about float, positioning, select styling and arictle: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/